# GeneXus X Evolution 2 Self-study

Tags: genexus

I have to use GeneXus X Evolution 2 for my project. But I don't know anything about it. I also don't know how to use this tools in web panel, how to write programs in it. I am completely beginner for it. It is frist time for me. So, I would like to learn starting from basic associated with  GeneXus X Evolution 2. If you have good links for online learning  or online ebook learning for it, could you guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://training.genexus.com/

Answer (score 2):

In adition to @Gilson's answer, [this is the GX training site](http://training.genexus.com/), where you can find all the relevant videos and materials for the different products.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous links you can also find all all sort of useful information regarding GeneXus at the wiki:
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Wiki+Home,

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link for the GeneXus channel @ youtube: https://www.youtube.com/user/GXMarketing
It has demos and tutorials that might help you